# Any way to disable syntax checking for a project?

Tags: eclipse

I created a project "Sample Code"... here I just paste sample code... much of it is snippets that won't compile.

Is there some project-specific setting I can make so that Eclipse doesn't try to compile it?

I would prefer not to have the source code littered with red error markers.

Comment: Why would you want to disable this? Its a rather useful feature

Comment: just on my "sample code" project... not on all my projects! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MY SOLUTION**

ok, this is not an exact solution to my problem... but it is another way to do it and I kinda like it now...

*I simply forget about using Eclipse to store the sample java files!*

I found a good program *CodeBox* for Mac to store code snippets and I'm sure there exist such things for Windows, Linux too...

there *interesting thing* is that when I choose from this program to open the java snippet file (.java) in an external editor (Eclipse), it will open in Eclipse *without any Syntax checking... wohoo! no squiggly lines*

Because of this, it is not full blown code highlighting... classes and variables same color... but that's ok.. still quite readable. Much more than if it was in Eclipse with syntax highlighting running on it...

So basically, if you want to get rid of these red squiggles... one way to do it is don't keep sample .java (or other language) files in a project in Eclipse... simply keep them in the filesystem or code storage app and open them with Eclipse when you want to view them.

Answer (score 1):

Put your code in a non-java project, ie a general project.

Downside: you will have to create package directory structure (unless you can copy and paste from somewhere else).

Upside: it won't try to compile.

Comment: doesn't work for me... red error flags still on any .java file I put in a "General Project"... is there some way to get rid of it? I must retain java syntax highlighting

Comment: Are you sure it is a project from the general category, and not a java project? the java builder should NOT run on a plain project.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you prefer to structure your project:

- you could put your java files into a separate folder that is not configured as a source folder. There is an entry in the eclipse help on [how to configure your build path](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm).
- or you can [set exclusion-patterns](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_api_classpath.htm) in the build configuration, so that specific packages or files that follow a pattern you define don't get compiled.

Yet another way to handle your snippets could be to use a [Scrapbook page](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_api_classpath.htm).
Eclipse won't highlight anything in a scrapbook page but you can select code parts inside the page and execute them isolated. That's nice if you're experimenting and don't want to set up a whole class with imports and methods just to see if a specific snippet works as expected.