# #include inside function body doesn't work (CDT/Eclipse C++)

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

This question concerns a C++ project managed with CDT 8.1.2 inside Eclipse 4.2.2 (Juno). The following code snippet will compile but it will be displayed as having errors inside Eclipse.

I have a file named foo.h which reads:

```
int a = 42;
```

This file is included in another file foo.cpp:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    #include "foo.h"
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

**How can I fix the "Symbol 'a' could not be resolved"?** In my understanding, the #include statement inside the main() function is supposed to trigger a mere copy-paste action in the preprocessor. CDT seems to have indexed the file correctly because I can CTRL-Click on the filename "foo.h" which then opens the file in the IDE.
Interestingly, if I move the `#include "foo.h"` statement just below the `#include <cstdio>` statement, it works as expected. Is there any option inside CDT to perform preprocessing before resolving symbols?

*Side note: I know that this code design is frowned upon, however I need to import code written by somebody else and require content assist set up properly in order to be productive.*

Comment: Where exactly are you getting this error? AFAIK this should work just fine, and as you intended.

Comment: I'm getting this error as soon as I create a minimal project with the content described above. The error is in the line with printf. I have to work on a project with some 500K LOC where the code is consistently written like above. Now CDT just won't let me use code assist which I really need.

Comment: @JohannesP I have used the code as given and it works for me! Using Code::Blocks BTW. So it must be something specific to CDT eclipse.

Comment: Just to clarify: You do **not** get this error when compiling, but just when CDT indexes the project, right?

Comment: @g-makulik yes, the code compiles fine, it's only about indexing and code assist in CDT. Using a different IDE would be a viable solution, too so I'm grateful for all hints to an IDE which can cope with this code style (like Code::Blocks). CDT would be preferred, though.

Comment: At my office I use SlickEdit.  We have a somewhat imposed structure from a parent company so most of our headers are multiply included, with conditional include sections based on what is included where.  SlickEdit rarely has any difficulty navigating our sources.  You can get a free trial, but after that it's fairly expensive.

Comment: Sure sounds like a CDT bug for this somewhat unusual case, I'd file a bug against CDT if I were you. One thing you could try is to put the 2nd #include on column 0 (i.e., don't indent it). I know that some old preprocessors (e.g., from Sun) had issues with that - probably not what's happening here.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there are many known issues with the code analyser in Eclipse. See for example this question [Turn off eclipse errors (that arent really errors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131939/turn-off-eclipse-errors-that-arent-really-errors) on how to disable some or all of the error messages. Not sure if that "solution" will be good enough for you but from what I understand it should not impact other aspects of the code indexer.

Comment: I'd say just turning off the errors, won't help for the OP's real problem, which focuses more on the usability of the indexers results (by means of correct intellisense and resolving declarations and definitions for navigation IMHO).

Answer (score 2):

Since any include should just turn out to be some "plain copy&paste" this may well be a bug in Eclipse/CDT.

#### If you use KDE you may try [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/).

I don't know whether there is everything around what you need but I just checked and there is at least no confusion about your minimal example above. (Code highlightning and assist is working as far as I can tell.)

[image]

Another quite popular IDE for Linux is **[Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/features/cpp/)**.
I can't give you any information on whether it will support that sort of "inline including" but both of them are popular and worth a try.

<sup>Perhaps this error is a "hint" for you to refrain from doing what your intention was. I don't know whoever would write code into a header that is mean to be included inline but instead of putting effort in a change of your IDE / search for a new one, you should probably refactor the code, There would be a greater benefit I think.</sup>

Comment: _' I don't know whoever would write code into a header that is mean to be included inline'_ Some weird code generation technique, maybe? I've also been thinking about proposing the KDevelop IDE, but it's pretty focused on KDE application development.

Comment: I'd generally suggest not to use such techniques then. ;) I don't know how the focus you mention affects the usability for other purposes since I didn't use KDevelop more than several month.

Comment: Of course not! But if you have to deal with what others left over :-( ... Regarding KDevelop I have to admit that I have not a single bit of experience with it, if it's completely transparent regarding toolchain settings it should do well if the preprocessor/parser/indexer catches this up (regarding Eclipse CDT I'd definitely consider this as a bug).

Comment: BTW: What would you think about [Qt Creator](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category:Tools::QtCreator) then? (left this out mentioning, because of the same reason)

Comment: Qt Creator may be appropriate, too. I know that there are many people using Qt Creator without developing Qt applications. There have to be reasons for that. I only added those IDEs I have already been using myself. (Eventhough I can't check the include problem in Netbeans at the moment). There are several IDEs out there worth trying, I guess. (Code::Blocks being another.)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, C++ include files (.h, or *header* files) should be included at the head of the module, not intermingled with the module's code.

It seems you have encountered an error with your development environment that in that it cannot properly handle a header file included in the middle of a function.

Move your `#include "foo.h"` statment above your `void main()...` statement and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As mentioned above, I already tried this and it works as expected. However, this is not an option since I do not control the code in which the developer group decided to just move away portions to separate header files. It is a valid concept since the code still compiles.

Comment: '_C++ include files must be included at the top of the module_' Can you show an official source for this rule? That's simply not true (good practice yes, but not true)

Comment: @g-makulik- I'm not saying that this is a rule, but it is convention, and most likely Johannes P has encountered a limitation of the compiler implementation.

Comment: Sorry @STLDeveloper but using the word "must" promotes the statement to a rule and the language allows includes almost anywhere.
The poster hadn't found a limitation of the compiler but the tool he uses to help during development

Comment: @STLDeveloper _'and most likely Johannes P has encountered a limitation of the compiler implementation'_ No he didn't (and states this clearly meanwhile). It's a problem with his IDE's (Eclipse CDT) indexer and intellisense solely.

Comment: @g-makulik, back on 6/8/13 when I first responded to Johnnes P's question, he certainly did not clearly state he had a problem with his IDE's indexer, and in fact he stated "CDT seems to have indexed the file correctly because I can Ctrl-Click on the filename 'foo.h' which then opens the file in the IDE.".  Much later, on 7/6/13, he added "The following code snippet will compile but it will be displayed as having errors inside Eclipse."

Comment: @g-makulik, my point is that your criticism was unwarranted based on the information that the OP supplied and the length of time since my response.  This question is a month old and the additional information was just added 2 days ago.  I was not alerted to this so that I could update my response.  I've adjusted it now.

Comment: @STLDeveloper Yes, that's why I've asked him to clarify at that time (and that's why I emphasized _'meanwhile'_ in my comment). So what's the matter? Does this circumstance make your answer better qualified for the actual question somehow? Your answer neither solves or even relates to the OP's problem (no more or less than the others do).

Answer (score 0):

Your latest update implies that you can use other IDEs.  Do they have to support GCC or are you limited to running on Linux or are you simply using CDT to provide call graphing and so on?

Can you use something like Visual Studio express to get the project compiling and use the tools available there to gain an understanding of how the code is structured?

It's unclear if you can actually use another IDE just to understand the code or if you need to be able to deliver it using the alternate IDE.

VS express 2012 works just fine with this style.

Comment: I have to use linux, so VS is not an option. I don't need the IDE to compile the project (it has its own make tool) but for content assist, call graphs, class hierarchy and other features.

Answer (score 0):

Some of my colleagues use [Source Insight](http://www.sourceinsight.com/index.html) (commercial, but fair price) and are pretty convinced about it. But unfortunately this is only available for Windows, it seems.

Besides [Code Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org) (as others already mentioned) you might try the [CodeLite IDE](http://www.codelite.org/), can't tell anything about their quality compared to Eclipse CDT.

Answer (score -1):

Type extern int a; ...............

Comment: Why? What should this change in this case? How shall it help remove the error? Also: putting an extern before a changes the semantic if "int a" is included inside a function like in the question.

Answer (score -1):

How about forward-declaring `int a;`?