# Eclipse CDT does not resolve variables initialized in #include files

Tags: c++, eclipse, include, eclipse-cdt

The problem occurs when trying to use CDT for editing files in OpenFOAM, a popular computational fluid dynamics software package. I am using Eclipse Kepler SR2 Build id: 20140224-0627 and CDT 8.3.0.201402142303 The following is a simplified version of the problem.

Given the following hello.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
    int main(){
        #include "hello.H"
        std::cout << hello << std::endl;
    }
```

and the following hello.H

```
std::string hello("Hello world!");
```

Indexing can't resolve hello in hello.cpp. However, if I change hello.H to hello.inc it does work. This isn't a feasible solution for OpenFOAM. How could I make the indexing and autocomplete work with the given structure?

Note: I did try Eclipse Luna too, and the same happened.

Edit: I think this might be a bug. After more experimenting, the following happened. When I named the hello.H to hello.inc, the hello in hello.cpp was recognized. However, when I rebuild index it wasn't. Then I resaved hello.inc without functional changes, and behold, it was recognized again. However, if I turned off automatic indexing it no longer got resolved after rebuilding the index.

Edit 2: After further research on the problem, I found the following duplicates, without the random behavior:
 https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=418085 
and to my shame:
 [#include inside function body doesn't work (CDT/Eclipse C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17004643/include-inside-function-body-doesnt-work-cdt-eclipse-c)
 Thus this question can be closed as a duplicate. To those interested, CDT indexer is not actually designed to do this, as this is bad coding style. The main message to me was that I should use some other IDE with OpenFoam.