# unorderd_set library inclusion error in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, stl

I am not able to compile the below code at eclipse.Can anyone let me know what can be reason although stl library is included for the same.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string str;
unordered_set <string> s;// symbol unordered_set can't be resolved
while(getline(cin,str)) // 
    {
    if(str=="exit")
            {
              break;
            }
    s.insert(str);
    }

return 1;
}
```

Comment: The [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) class is part of C++11, have you enabled it for your compiler? I don't know if Eclipse have a special toggle for this, otherwise you have to add the flag `-std=c++11` (or if your compiler is a little old `-std=c++1x`, and if your compiler is much to old you can't use it at all).

Comment: Yes , I have enabled it for my compiler and eclipse is not giving any error while including this class, but not sure why it is giving while creating object of this class.

Comment: you don't have `#include <string>`; is string included anywhere?

Comment: Oh, I believe these are the bogus errors from Codan, see [Turn off eclipse errors (that arent really errors)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14131939/341970) for a workaround.

Comment: i don't require to add the string class , it works without this.