# Compiling error with unsigned and int

Tags: eclipse, xcode, warnings

I'm using Eclipse and xCode to develop in C++.

The problem is in Eclipse I used the following statement:

```
unsigned asdf = -1;
```

In eclipse it worked fine, but in xcode is not letting you compile. How can I specify in Eclipses's settings to not let me compile if there is something like this?

Comment: Ops, sorry. It doesn't let you compile.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this warning is `-Wsign-conversion` being used by Xcode.  Obviously you are compiling under Eclipse without this warning.  This is a good warning (most are) so the better solution is to fix the code and *up* the warnings in Eclipse to match Xcode.

I am not near my Mac at the moment so I cannot show you a screenshot of Xcode, however you should be able to find this warning and disable it in your project settings, if you don't wish to fix the code.

Comment: That is what I want. Match the warnings. But I don't know where is it in Eclipse.

Comment: @user3468999 Look at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131939/turn-off-eclipse-errors-that-arent-really-errors

Answer (score 0):

The error should be the fact that you don't declare what the type of variable, try

`unsigned int asdf = -1;`

Comment: No, that's not the issue.